# Variable importance in decision tree of caret package in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-caret

I am using the Caret package in R for training the tree based models for a classification problem. I have been able to get the trees, accuracy, etc., but I also want the importance of the variables (in decreasing order of importance) according to the decision tree constructed/ otherwise.

What are the different ways to do so (especially Variable Importance based on the Decision tree constructed) ?

Comment: Have you tried the build-in `varImp` function of the `caret` package?

Comment: @MarcelG Yes I did: It gave the following error: Error in roc.default(cls, dat) : No control observation.
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: That error does not ring a bell. However, many decision tree packages have their own variable importance functions, e.g. `importance` in the `randomForest` package. I suggest you try the variable importance function of the package you use through `caret` directly.

Comment: @humble_me Please provide a short and reproducible example of how you construct the tree model and call the variable importance function.